# How to align links, videos, photos properly

Tags: html

If I click on any part of sign out row I got sign out and have some more issue like this.

I am not able to align links,videos,photos etc in right way. For example I have aligned sign out on right side page but when i click on any area which falls in the row area (in which sign out is placed), I got sign out but I want when I click only on link I get sign out.

I have used photos in my pages and videos. I have placed photos in a table in less than half of page width. I want that in remaining half area videos player appreas. But I am not able to do this.

I am sending you my files please check and tell me correct method to align these things I think Div will be used but I don't know if this is prooper use. Please suggest me what should I do.

Home_page.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>


<body background="bg.JPG">

<table>
<tr><td><?php include('search_file.php'); ?></td>
<td><?php include('google.php'); ?></td>
</table>

<font color="red"><b><h2 align="center">Deepak Narwal Welcomes You</h2></b></font>
<hr size="2" width="50%">

<a  href="logout_file.php"><h3 align="right">Sign Out</h3></a>
<?php include("photo_upload.php"); ?>
<br /><br /><br /><br />

<?php include("video_upload.php"); ?>

<br /><a href="upload_file.php"><h4>Up-Load Files</h4></a>
<br /><br />

<a href="list_files.php"><h4>List All Up-Loaded Files</h4></a>



</body>
</html>
```

Next file in which i have used photos are

```
photo_upload.php

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeimage(n)
  {
    var img=document.getElementById("sample");
if(n==1) 
 {
   img.src="16.jpg";
 }
 else
 {
  img.src="5.jpg";
 }
}
</script>
</head> 




<body>
<table cellpadding=10 cellspacing=6 align=left border=1>

<tr>
<td><a href="kat.JPG"><img src="kat.JPG" width="200" height="150" border="0" alt="katrina"></a></td>
<td><a href="kat2.JPG" ><img src="5.jpg"  border="0" width="200" height="150" id ="sample" alt="sample" onmouseover="changeimage(1)" onmouseout="changeimage(2)"></a></td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="kat3.JPG"><img src="kat3.JPG" width="200" height="150" border="0"></a></td>
<td><a href="kat4.JPG"><img src="kat4.JPG" width="200" height="150" border="0"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

For videos my file is

```
video_upload.php
<html>
<head>
    <script src="flowplayer-3.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<a 
    style="display:block;width:300px;height:250px;position:relative;left:1054;"  
    id="player">
</a>

<script language="JavaScript">
    flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.1.5.swf" , { clip: { autoPlay : false, autoBuffering: true},   playlist: [ 'video.flv', 'flowplayer.flv'] });  //create a object of clip name
</script>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br />



<object classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616" align="right" width="320" height="260" codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab">
<param name="custommode" value="none" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="autoPlay" value="false" />
    <param name="autoBuffering" value="true" />
    <param name="src" value="http://localhost/idiot.mkv" />
<embed type="video/divx" src="http://localhost/idiot.mkv" custommode="none" width="300" height="250" previewImage="deepak.JPG" loop="true"  autoPlay="false"  pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/">
</embed>
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

Tell me how I can align pics in half width area and videos in next half width area in same rows.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get rid of the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags in `video_upload.php` and `photo_upload.php`.
You are including these files into your main HTML page! This already has those tags. You **cannot** have an `html` tag inside the `body` tag again.

You should read about the [structure of HTML documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element).

And for the layout, well it is hard to tell without actually seeing how it looks like. Maybe you want to ask at [doctype.com](http://doctype.com/) as this question is more about design.

Comment: Thanks flix I have out this question on doctype also.If you want to see snapshots i can send via mail.Can i atatch here

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).